# MAUI: Windows platform reads App.config but Android doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm implementing a `MAUI` project. I've added an `App.config` file to read the connection string from a previous existing `Data` layer that works fine.

The thing is that when I run the `Windows platform` application I don't have any problem and everything works perfect. But when I run the `Android` application I have a `NullReferenceException` when reading the `ConnectionString`.

Does anyone know what can it be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android doesn’t support the underlying infrastructure to make app.config work.  I believe there are nuget packages you can use to get similar function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read app configuration through a appsettings.json file. You may refer to [Sample project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/dotnet-maui-configuration/tree/master/MauiApp27) on GitHub and
**James Montemagno**'s article [App Configuration Settings in .NET MAUI (appsettings.json)](https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/).

To sum up:

1.Create a config json file and set the BuildAction to **EmbeddedResource**.

2.add config file to builder.Configuration:

```
 var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("YourProjectName.appsettings.json");

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonStream(stream)
        .Build();


builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

3.For android, you could get the configure in any other places:

```
IConfiguration configuration;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var serviceProvider = MauiApplication.Current.Services;
    configuration = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration)) as IConfiguration;
}
```

I think there might be other alternatives, such as [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android) and [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new with MAUI and you explained your answer perfectly! Thanks again!